# how to use $or operator in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

I am trying to query on CouchDB like below

```
[{
    "selector": {
        "docType": "student_details",
        {
            $or: ["studentName": {
                "$regex": "John"
            }, "studentAge": {
                "$regex": "15"
            }]
        }
    }
}]
```

but it is not working. Indexes are created on "studentName" and "studentAge". I am trying to get an output if either of the expression has a result.

However the following query works,

```
[{
    "selector": {
        "docType": "student_details",
        "studentName": {
            "$regex": "John"
        }
    }
}]
```

This gives me an output for `studentName` with John

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your first JSON is not of valid format. Also CouchDB expects operators to be enclosed in double quotes but `$or` is missing them.

You don't need to use `$regex` if you look for equality, the `$eq` operator is better suited. The `selector` can be written as follows.

```
"selector": { 
   "docType": "student_details",
   "$or": [ 
      { 
         "studentName": { 
            "$eq": "John"
         }
      },
      { 
         "studentAge": { 
            "$eq": 15
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Or even simpler with implicit operators (not an option if you really have to use `$regex`).

```
"selector": { 
   "docType": "student_details",
   "$or": [ 
       { "studentName": "John" },
       { "studentAge": 15 }
   ]
}
```

> Please note that this solution presumes that `studentAge` is of type `number`.

Comment: Hi Uminder, the reason why I am using regex is because I'll be using this query for a search functionality. So if I search "ohn" instead of "John" it should give the same result. Anyways thanks for your help, the $regex query worked looks like i had a syntax error while firing the query.